# enabling SSL - IIS proxying weblogic server

Tags: iis, ssl, weblogic

I've enabled SSL on IIS server (running on Windows 2003) using steps mentioned here:

http://www.techpaste.com/2012/01/steps-configure-ssl-iis-windows-2003-server/

It looks like SSL is enabled properly because when I hit:

```
http://hostname.myhost
```

I get following in browser:

> The page must be viewed over a secure channel The page you are trying
>   to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
>
> Please try the following:
>
> ```
> Type https:// at the beginning of the address you are attempting to reach and press ENTER.
> ```

I was using this IIS as proxy to my weblogic server. All my configuration was working on HTTP (http://hostname.myhost/myapp/test.jsp).

However when I tried (HTTPS):

```
https://myhost/myapp/test.jsp
```

It doesn't work. I get following in browser:

```
The connection was interrupted
```

After googling, I found that I'll need to enable HTTPS on weblogic and I'll have to establish trust between IIS plugin and weblogic.

```
URL - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/plugins/isapi.html#100382
Section: Using SSL with the Microsoft Internet Information Server Plug-In
```

I enabled HTTPS on weblogic by checking 'SSL Listen Port Enabled'.
Using keytool and java command, I got pem file as well for corresponding der file for corresponding certificate in DemoTrust.jks.
I added following two keys to iisproxy.ini file:

```
SecureProxy=ON
TrustedCAFile=c:/mycert.pem
```

However when I access https://hostname.myhost/myapp/test.jsp, I still get same error in browser.
In iisforward.log I see following:

```
Fri Aug 02 14:52:29 2013 load properties from: C:\Inetpub\WLS_IIS_Plugin\iisproxy.ini
Fri Aug 02 14:52:29 2013 WLForwardPath: /
Fri Aug 02 14:54:36 2013 TerminateFilter...
```

I don't see any log in iisproxy.log.

Could anyone please suggest where I am wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the iis once...

Before resetting iis the following things make sure...

you have enabled SSL port in weblogic console and make sure you have enabled that port in that server's firewall. otherwise it won't allow any outside/remote communication via that port

you have to bind an ip addess and port in IIS for ssl communication...and you must have to specify SecureProxy=ON in iisproxy.ini(the cert should be physically located..where it is specified in iisproxy.ini file like c:/mycert.pem)